# Symfony remove button from filetype

Tags: php, twig, symfony

In Symfony when I render my filetype field it places the button in the field itself. How can I remove the button altogether or at least have the button and text field separate and apply my own CSS style to them?

Here is an example of the page:

[image: File Browser]

### PHP

```php
$builder->add('filebrowser', FileType::class, array(
        'mapped' => false,
        'label' => 'Upload file')
    );
```

### Twig

```
{{ form_label(cv.filebrowser) }}
{{ form_errors(cv.filebrowser) }}
{{ form_widget(cv.filebrowser) }}
```

Comment: how do you render the field in the twig template? Can you post the code?

Comment: I iterate over the form using a loop that's why I have 'cv' in the Twig field.